# Php, jQuery, and AJAX interaction and data manipulation

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm looking for some basic guidance. I understand jQuery. And I understand PHP. I'm having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around utilizing AJAX.

I can use AJAX to pull data from PHP and subsequent database content, but how to I use it in the HTML?

What I'm accustomed to:

```
<?php
echo '<html><head></head><body>';

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE field='.$field.'");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    if (str_len($name >= 15)) { $name = substr($name,0,15)."..."; }
    $icon = '';
    switch($id) {
      case 1: $icon = 'A';
      case 2: $icon = 'B';
      case 3: $icon = 'C';
     }

      echo '<a href="#'.$id.'">'.$icon.$name.'</a><br />';
 }


 echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

**How do I use AJAX in a similar fashion? 
Or should I even try something similar with AJAX?**

For example, I can do this (inside surrounding correct HTML):

```
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',         
      data: "", 
      dataType: 'json',       
      success: function(rows)  
      {
        for (var i in rows) {
        var row = rows[i];
            var id = row[0]; 
        var vname = row[1]; 
            $('#output').html('<a href="#id'+id+'">'+vname+'</a><br />'); 
            }
    }
  });
```

What I'm having difficulty with is understanding how to implement the switch and other data manipulations as AJAX items/data/objects.

The api data call is similar to this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE field =$field");        
  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $data[]=$row;
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
```

Is this where I should manipulate the data? If so, is there a specific manner which is best?:

**Do I simply set up the data manipulations in PHP? If so, how to do pass that data via AJAX properly?**

Or should I be using jQuery/javascript to perform all data manipulations?

I've searched and 90% of the AJAX tutorials I find are simple in nature and aren't really explaining these sort of things.

Edit:
General console output of the JSON data looks like this:

```
success: function(data)  
      {
       $.each(data, function(index, item){
        var name;
        for(name in item){ console.log(name + " = " + item[name]);}
        });
     }
```

and the console:

```
{ 0 = id }
{ 1 = name }
{ 2 = 3.7 }
{ 3 = Y }
{ 4 = 0 }
```

Comment: Can you perhaps give an example of the JSON you are outputting from your Ajax call to `api.php`

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I've edited. Is that what you were after?

Comment: Can we see sample output to give you a more direct answer as opposed to some hypothetical solution.

Comment: I can't actually share specific data. The best I can do is a similar hypothetical data stream.

Comment: @MackieeE I don't need to "send" info to the php file. I need to manipulate the data the PHP file is generating. Please read again.

Comment: OK - then make some up, change the column names and the data, whatever you want. I just wanted something that you can relate to.

Comment: uhm.... I made up "id" and "name". They are relatable.

Comment: Sorry! I mis-read that, id and name was from the query result :).. but within the Success function then, you can use the $.parseJSON http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ to pick the return data

Answer (score 0):

OK Consider returned JSON in this structure

```
{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"}
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"}
    ]
}}
```

Then you would do something like this to append a list of `<a>`'s to your `#output`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        items = data.menu.items;
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            $('#output').append('<a href="#id' + item.id + '">' + item.label + '</a><br />');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps this is what I wasn't understanding in the previous comments. where does "menu.items" come into play? Is menu the table name? I'll update the question with some console output.

Comment: Look at the JSON structure! That's why i asked you for some of your specific JSON to make it more understandable!  `menu` is the root node of the JSON structure. `items` are the children of the menu node - aswell as `header` but there is only one value/node for `heade`r rather than multiple children.  `menu` could be called `jellybeans` aswell and then your `items` would come from `items = data.jellybeans.items`

Comment: I'm not trying to upset anyone. Not sure why you seem to be yelling with exclamation marks. This is the part I'm having difficulty understanding or finding an explanation of -- the data manipulation. I don't know how to configure the JSON data into a usable format the same way I can configure PHP data.

Comment: You're not upsetting anyone!   It's just much easier to work with real examples rather than hypothetical confectionery! Try giving your JSON a rootnode to work from.
Instead of `$data[]=$row;` in your php try `$data['jellybeans']=$row;` that way all your `rows` will reside under the `jellybean` node.  Since you are telling your Ajax function that it is expecting JSON it will automatically parse the response as JSON which it turns into an object which you can loop through various parts of as needed.